# Single view subscribes to multiple Meteor publishes onWait

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I return two `Meteor.subscribe()` methods in my `waitOn` method?  I am trying to render two collections' publications in a single view. I currently have

```
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('lists');
   //return Meteor.subscribe('details');
}
```

But I obviously can't return twice.

Comment: did you try this? `return [Meteor.subscribe('lists'),Meteor.subscribe('details')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
waitOn:function(){  
return
  [
   Meteor.subscribe('first'),
   Meteor.subscribe('second')
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Sasikanath sorry i didn't see your answer, my internet connection get really slow

Comment: @Ethaan, thanks for the edit, typed that in android app